# Downloading meta content for around 15000 URL Python - threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous

I have around 30000 Urls in my csv. I need to check if it has meta content is present or not, for each url. I am using request_cache to basically cache the response to a sqlite db. It was taking about 24hrs even after using a caching sys. Therefore I moved to concurrency. I think I have done something wrong with `out = executor.map(download_site, sites, headers)`. And do not know how to fix it.

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

```
import concurrent.futures
import requests
import threading
import time
import pandas as pd
import requests_cache
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

thread_local = threading.local()

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

sites = []
for row in df['URLS']:
    sites.append(row)

# print("URL is shortened")

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'
headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,}

requests_cache.install_cache('network_call', backend='sqlite', expire_after=2592000)


def getSess():
    if not hasattr(thread_local, "session"):
        thread_local.session = requests.Session()
    return thread_local.session

def networkCall(url, headers):
    print("In Download site")
    session = getSess()
    with session.get(url, headers=headers) as response:
        print(f"Read {len(response.content)} from {url}")
        return response.content

out = []
def getMeta(meta_res):
    print("Get data")
    for each in meta_res:
        meta = each.find_all('meta')
        for tag in meta:
            if 'name' in tag.attrs.keys() and tag.attrs['name'].strip().lower() in ['description', 'keywords']:
                content = tag.attrs['content']
                if content != '':
                    out.append("Absent")
                else:
                    out.append("Present")
    return out


def allSites(sites):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
        out = executor.map(networkCall, sites, headers)
        return list(out)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sites = [
    "https://www.jython.org",
    "http://olympus.realpython.org/dice",
    ] * 15000
    start_time = time.time()
    list_meta = allSites(sites)
    print("META   ", list_meta)
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    print(f"Downloaded {len(sites)} in {duration} seconds")
    output = getMeta(list_meta)
    df["is it there"] = pd.Series(output)
    df.to_csv('new.csv',index=False, header=True)
```

Comment: This code is not runnable because it's missing a couple of functions. You also need to bear in mind that even if your code is as efficient as possible, you may be constrained by the time it takes for the various URLs to respond to HTTP GET

Comment: Have you tried using asyncio? I've had some success speeding up querying several hundreds pages.

Comment: @DarkKnight it is runnable, just comment the df[test.csv] part. I have given the site var under if __name__ == "__main__":.

Comment: @MariaZentsova ah that is going to my last resort

Comment: It is **not** runnable because both *download_sites* and *get_session* are missing

Comment: @DarkKnight ahh sorry, changed it. Should run now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to emulate your functionality. The following code executes in under 4 minutes:-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import concurrent.futures
import time
import queue
import requests


URLs = [
    "https://www.jython.org",
    "http://olympus.realpython.org/dice"
] * 15_000

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}


class SessionCache():
    def __init__(self, cachesize=20):
        self.cachesize = cachesize
        self.sessions = 0
        self.q = queue.Queue()

    def getSession(self):
        try:
            return self.q.get(block=False)
        except queue.Empty:
            pass
        if self.sessions < self.cachesize:
            self.q.put(requests.Session())
            self.sessions += 1
        return self.q.get()

    def putSession(self, session):
        self.q.put(session)


CACHE = SessionCache()


def doGet(url):
    try:
        session = CACHE.getSession()
        response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()
        soup = BS(response.text, 'lxml')
        for meta in soup.find_all('meta'):
            if (name := meta.attrs.get('name', None)):
                if name.strip().lower() in ['description', 'keywords']:
                    if meta.attrs.get('content', '') != '':
                        return url, 'Present'
        return url, 'Absent'
    except Exception as e:
        return url, str(e)
    finally:
        CACHE.putSession(session)


def main():
    start = time.perf_counter()
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for r in executor.map(doGet, URLs):
            print(f'{r[0]} -> {r[1]}')
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Duration={end-start:.4f}s')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is giving a sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

Comment: I have no idea why that would be. Take that up with the author(s) of *requests_cache*

Comment: I've edited my answer to remove the dependency on *requests_cache*

Answer (score 1):

Just recently stumbled upon a library for making async requests, it is called [requests-futures](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures).

The syntax is pretty simple:

```
from concurrent.futures import as_completed
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

URLs = [

    'https://www.jython.org',
     'http://olympus.realpython.org/dice'
] * 1000



def scrape(URLs):

    with FuturesSession() as session:
        out = []
        futures = [session.get(url) for url in URLs]
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            resp = future.result()
            pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')
            meta = pageSoup.find_all("meta")
            for tag in meta:
                if 'name' in tag.attrs.keys() and tag.attrs['name'].strip().lower() in ['description', 'keywords']:
                    content = tag.attrs['content']
                    if content != '':
                        out.append("Absent")
                    else:
                        out.append("Present")
        return out
```

So, it essentially took less then a minute to scrape 2,000 URLs

```
%%time
data = scrape(URLs)
```

CPU times: user 13.5 s, sys: 801 ms, total: 14.3 s
Wall time: 30.1 s

Answer (score 0):

## AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

This error is happening in `requests.models.PrepareRequest.prepare_headers()`. When you call `executor.map(networkCall, sites, headers)`, it's casting `headers` to a list, so you end up with `request.headers = 'User-Agent'` instead of `request.headers = {'User-Agent': '...'}`.

Since it looks like the headers aren't actually changing, you can make that a constant and remove it as an argument from `networkCall()`:

```py
HEADERS = {'User-Agent':user_agent}
...

def networkCall(url):
    session = getSess()
    with session.get(url, headers=HEADERS) as response:
        print(f"Read {len(response.content)} from {url}")
        return response.content
...

def allSites(sites):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
        out = executor.map(networkCall, sites)
        return list(out)
```

## sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

Another thing worth noting is that `requests_cache.install_cache()` is **not** thread-safe, which causes the `sqlite3.OperationalError` you got earlier. You can remove `install_cache()` and use `requests_cache.CachedSession` instead, which **is** thread-safe:

```py
def getSess():
    if not hasattr(thread_local, "session"):
        thread_local.session = requests_cache.CachedSession(
            'network_call',
            backend='sqlite',
            expire_after=2592000,
        )
    return thread_local.session
```

For reference, there's more info in the requests-cache user guide on the [differences between sessions and patching](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/general.html).

## Performance

A note on performance: Since you're doing lots of concurrent writes, SQLite isn't ideal. It's fast for concurrent reads, but for writes it internally queues operations and writes data in serial, not in parallel. If possible, try using Redis or one of the other [requests-cache backends](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/backends.html), which are better optimized for concurrent writes.